# Help to identify an uncommon thermistor

Tags: identification, thermistor

I am trying to identify a thermistor that was used in a "smart thermostat". It is a surface mounted small part  (0603 form factor), bears no markings. 
I measured the resistance across at a few temperatures, and got (approximately, perhaps 5% error):

- 49°F: 16.05kΩ
- 79°F: 11.1kΩ
- 81°F: 10.94kΩ
- 97°F: 10.14 - 10.2kΩ

I also tested the board with a standard 10KΩ thermistor (Type 2, though at room temperature that does not matter) and, predictably, it was showing about 10-15°F too high of a temperature.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

A much more accurate approach would be to replace the thermistor with a cermet trimpot and adjust the pot until you get specific readings in degrees C, then disconnect and measure the pot resistance.

You can then find B0/50,B25/50,B25/75,B25/85 and compare to (say) Digikey's filters. Also find the resistance at 25°C (77°F).

So, resistances at 32°F/77°F/122°F/167°F/185°F. If the display does not go up that high, it might be necessary to use lower values and compare.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting - I'll see if I can set this up.

In this case it's a cheapo "smart thermostat" I got off of ebay, though - so it can't be a very unusual part. So, in the meantime if anyone has suggestions of something relatively standard that fits the values approx. (11K thermistor? Is there such a thing?) - that'd be great.

Comment: If you take the numbers you have (77°F is the key number) and search Digikey you'll find 10.5K, 10.74K, 11K, 12K. Of those, 12K seems to be the only available one in SMT and in stock, but it's 0402. Call me skeptical, but I'm a bit dubious it's other than 10K. You may need to wait quite a while after soldering to get an accurate reading.

Comment: I expected it to be a 10K as well, but curiously did not seem to be.  I tested the device with a known 10K thermistor and got a higher tempeature reading  (reading 86F at room temperature of about 76F). The thermistor I tested had wire leads, and was well cooled down. The result more or less matched what I measured.

Comment: Another possibility is that there is some kind of calibration adjustment in the device that is factory set. Typically stored in EEPROM on a microcontroller. I could see that being off by that amount if it was erased.

Comment: Since the device was reset a few times with the original thermistor attached - and readings did not change, I assume that there is either no adjustment or it is permanent. I found a number of 12K thermistors - certainly seems like a possibility. Will try to follow your original suggestion and build a better temp. graph.

Comment: Thanks again for the suggestion - your method worked very well. Based on the measurements this is a 10K Beta 3435 (85/25) thermistor. Ordered, will test.